# TypeError: $(...) not a function error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I already checked old threads, but still I could not solve it.

It's regading jquery  think but I already put jquery in the file.

can someone tell me what is the issue here?

Code is about displaying the graph and on button click of slice display nother graph.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>

</head>
    <body>

    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

    </body>
        <script>
    $(function () {
            $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: 1,//null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2014'
            },
            tooltip: {

                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                    style: {
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'

                    }
                }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Browser share',

                data: [
                ['Firefox',   45.0],
                ['IE',       26.8],
                {
                name: 'Chrome',
                y: 12.8,
                sliced: true,
                    selected: true
            },
        ['Safari',    8.5],
            ['Opera',     6.2],
            ['Others',   0.7]
            ]
            }]
            });
        });       
        </script>
<html>
```

Comment: Why are you including two different jQuery versions?

Answer (score 3):

Highcharts depends on jQuery. So you must include jQuery *before* highcharts.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer to JQuery before refering to highchart scripts.

A few changes would be:

1. refer to just one JQuery
2. Inclose your script in **$(document).ready(function(){});**

Please see the updated code:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

</head>
    <body>

    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

    </body>
        <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function () {
            $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: 1,//null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2014'
            },
            tooltip: {

                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                    style: {
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'

                    }
                }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Browser share',

                data: [
                ['Firefox',   45.0],
                ['IE',       26.8],
                {
                name: 'Chrome',
                y: 12.8,
                sliced: true,
                    selected: true
            },
        ['Safari',    8.5],
            ['Opera',     6.2],
            ['Others',   0.7]
            ]
            }]
            });
        });    
 });    
        </script>
<html>
```